# some images not load in android 7+ (api24+)

Tags: android, imageview, picasso, android-glide, android-7.0-nougat

i use picasso for load images in imageView from **assets**.

```
android 4.1.2: working fine.

android 5.1 : working fine.

android 7.0+ : not Working.
```

I use glide but be same.
what i have to do?

Comment: You have to write a better post then this one to begin with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**problem Solved!**

this problem happened because pictures size was 1300x900 .
i change them to 700x300.
now working nice
good luck

Comment: hi . you had to resize your pictures and then use them in your app